# matlab smooth vertical and horizontal rectangle

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, robotics, image-morphology

Could someone help me to find what morphological operations should I use in order to smoothen the vertical and horizontal rectangle on this image

[image]

More precisely what I would want is that the white rectangles become continuous. The final application of that would be to detect vertical and horizontal lines in the image, indeed this image is a map where white element represent obstacle and where i would want to detect the walls.

So the result i would want should be something like that:

[image]

Comment: could you please upload some visualization of the desired output?

Comment: Yep, that will be easier to understand what i want!

Comment: Try imdilate or imclose

Comment: I already tried that with many different structuring element but it did not work...